# Woocommerce filter by attribute causes any widget to fail

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've been trying all day, and although I am a woocommmerce scrub, I am also a dev of 20 years experience.  Have tried resetting & uninstalling the local-wp env several times.

How to reproduce the issue :

1/ add a few categories

2/ add an attribute

3/ add an attribute to product

4/ add the woocommerce widget "filter by product attribute" to any page

5/ watch it fail.

I am using WooCommerce Version 5.5.2

And WP 5.8

I swear I had this working earlier today, but I deleted a product and added some new attributes and now, it's just broken, with no amount of uninstalling helping.

Whenever I add a filter products by attribute element I get an ice cream and this error message

```
react-dom.min.js?ver=16.13.1:125 TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
at Se (attribute-filter-frontend.js?ver=0d16e9e72c6ee9733f7cfce0ac033dac:14)
at we (react-dom.min.js?ver=16.13.1:84)
at zj (react-dom.min.js?ver=16.13.1:226)
at Th (react-dom.min.js?ver=16.13.1:152)
at tj (react-dom.min.js?ver=16.13.1:152)
at Te (react-dom.min.js?ver=16.13.1:146)
at Ja (react-dom.min.js?ver=16.13.1:224)
at md (react-dom.min.js?ver=16.13.1:173)
at react-dom.min.js?ver=16.13.1:175
at Rh (react-dom.min.js?ver=16.13.1:147)
```

[screen grab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sk36.png)

Comment: Don't forget to click the "Enable Archives" box when you create any new product attribute.